# Browser back button and duplicate data entry

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-headers, back-button, duplicates, no-cache

I follow the PRG pattern to avoid form resubmission problem when page is refreshed. These are the  action metods:

```
   public ViewResult AddDcoument(){
      .....
      return View();
   }

   [HttpPost]
   public RedirectToRouteResult SaveDocument(Document doc){
      //save the document
      return RedirectToAction("ViewDocument",new { docId =doc.DocID});
   }

   public ViewResult ViewDocument(string docID){
      Document doc=GetDocumentByID(docID);
      return View(doc);
   }
```

When I hit the submit button the document is saved and I get redirected to ViewDocument action and this helps prevent form resubmission when the page is refreshed. But there's another problem, the problem is I can still click the browser back button, which will take me back to the data entry form with all the previously entered data remaining and I can easily click submit again, which means duplicate entry.
 Now one might say that I need to have something that is unique for an entry that will not let a duplicate to be saved to server. In fact I have it and that is the DocumentID, but it's assigned automatically, not by user input. So how do you handle this case?

UPDATE: I actualy found a way around this issue. As per [this blog](http://blog.55minutes.com/2011/10/how-to-defeat-the-browser-back-button-cache/) and many other SO threads I need to supply the following Http header in order to turn off browser caching:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-store
```

I've tried both the following ways:

The encapsulated, OOP way:

```
var cache=Response.Cache;
cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
cache.SetNoStore();
```

And by simply appending the header string:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-store");
```

I tried adding them both to the GET method that renders the form and to the POST method that submits the form. But still the form inputs are repopulated from cache.

Comment: One possible solution described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207996/how-to-prevent-duplicate-form-submission-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I the cookie approach.